# how to dynamically insert column value into table2 select * from another table1 which is having one column less than table2

Tags: oracle, plsql

table1 :

```
t1_column1  t1_column2  t1_column3
 1           2           3
 2           3           4
```

---

```
table2 is : 

t2_column1  t2_column2  t2_column3   t2_column4
 1           2           3             0
 2           3           4             0
```

> Here I am passing the value as function argument, but when I am
>   trying to create this function getting this error : Error(11,7):
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored   and Error(11,108): PL/SQL: ORA-00917:
>   missing comma

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_PURCHASE(GODOWN_CODE IN VARCHAR2,MON IN 
VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   var_mon VARCHAR2(100);
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN
var_mon:=MON;

  INSERT INTO table2  
( t2_column1, t2_column2, t2_column3, var_mon)
SELECT  t1_column1, t1_column2, t1_column3 
FROM table1   WHERE  t1_column1=GODOWN_CODE;
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE  t1_column1=GODOWN_CODE;

    COMMIT;        
  RETURN 'done';
 END NEW_PURCHASE;
```

Comment: `t2.mon as var_mon` This is wrong

Comment: It should work then.  Also what happened to your last question. You didnot close that by accepting any answer.

Comment: there is no need to use column aliases in an insert statement. As @XING has said 't2.mon as var_mon' is wrong. Just remove the column aliases from the insert column list and the select column list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_PURCHASE (GODOWN_CODE   IN VARCHAR2,
                                         MON           IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   --var_mon   VARCHAR2 (100);
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   --var_mon := 'MON';

   INSERT INTO table2 (t2_column1,
                       t2_column2,
                       t2_column3,
                       t2_column4)
      SELECT t1_column1, t1_column2, t1_column3, mon           
      FROM table1
       WHERE t1_column1 = GODOWN_CODE;

   DELETE FROM table1
         WHERE t1_column1 = GODOWN_CODE;

   COMMIT;
   RETURN 'done';
END NEW_PURCHASE;
```

Note that if you do `DML` operation in a `function`, you `cannot` call it from a `select` statement, You would need a PLSQL block to run it.

For ex:

You can call it as below:

```
declare
   l_message varchar2(30);
begin
   l_message := test_func('123');
end;
```

... but not like this:

```
select test_func(empno) from emp;
```

Comment: with this can I insert mon value into t2_column4?, here I think 'MON' is string, but I want to insert MON argument value into table2 t2_column4

Comment: `MON` is not a string. Its the value you are passing. Dont post any reply without trying the solution and incase you get any issue do post it as well

Comment: I called function  like this, but in last column instead of 30, MON inserted                                                                                                                                       
   declare                                                                                    
    l_message varchar2(30);                                                                                                               
    BEGIN
    L_MESSAGE := NEW_PURCHASE('12','30');
   end;

Comment: I accepted your answer, I was selected like 'MON', realized now